# Extract the mass of the held object in Steam VR unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, reference, virtual-reality

I am very new to unity and C#. I'm making a game which needs to be able to extract the mass of the currently held object in VR. So, if I'm holding an object, I want to be able to know and log the value of the rigidbody mass.

Could anyone help me or send me to an example scene?

I have tried a bunch of different methods, but my C# knowledge just is not good enough to be able to use the limited amount of info I have found online.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the `Rigidbody` from the `Interactable` (or from any `MonoBehaviour`) you are holding with `GetComponent<Rigidbody>().mass`. If it can change and you need to get the value several times, you should save the `Rigidbody`'s reference on grabbing and null it on ungrab.